# NameError: name X is not defined

Tags: python

InPut:-

```py
from sklearn import svm #Creating a svm classifier model

clf=svm.SVC(gamma=.001,probability=True) #train_data_flat_tModel training
 
train = clf.fit(train_data_flat_t, train_labels)
predicted= clf.predict(test_data_flat_t)
 
 
score = clf.score(test_data_flat_t,test_labels)
print("score",score)
 
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(np.mean(score)))
```

OutPut:-

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-50a70d105279> in <module>
      3 clf=svm.SVC(gamma=.001,probability=True) #train_data_flat_tModel training
      4 
----> 5 train = clf.fit(train_data_flat_t, train_labels)
      6 predicted= clf.predict(test_data_flat_t)
      7 

NameError: name 'train_data_flat_t' is not defined
```

Please help me to bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

NameErrors occur when you didn't define the thing you are calling. If I run:

```
print(TheBestNumber)
```

It will tell me "NameError: name 'TheBestNumber' is not defined", because I didn't tell it what "TheBestNumber" is. But if I write:

```
TheBestNumber = 69
print(TheBestNumber)
```

It will correctly tell me "69". Your problem is basically the same as this; you didn't define the thing you are trying to use.

Comment: But here the print is not the train_data_flat_t, it sore.
and the Error it's giving on train_data_flat_t.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see your problem - you've become confused by the feature that IPython writes out the return value when you call functions.
Your variable `clf` may have the type or value `train_data_flat_tModel` but that doesn't mean that you have a variable named `train_data_flat_t` available.

Possibly your `clf` has a value `train_data_flat_t` and `train_labels` (aka try `clf.train_data_flat_t` instead of just `train_data_flat_t`).

But in general, from where do you expect to get your `train_data_flat_t`, `train_labels`, `test_data_flat_t` and `test_labels`?

Maybe you need to import it from `sklearn`.